# Dynamic number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to convert this

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1 |
| Name1 | 2 |
| Name2 | 3 |
| Name2 | 4 |
| Name2 | 5 |
| Name3 | 6 |

into something like this?

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 |  |
|  | 5 |  |

The number of columns depends on the number of unique names.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "dynamic".  There is nothing dynamic in your results.

Comment: What you are asking for is a `pivot`, if your column names are known then it's not dynamic however.

Comment: I mean the number of columns will depend on the number of unique names

Comment: Things to remember about dynamic pivots: they are difficult to write and debug correctly, and are rarely necessary Most times you should be sticking to fixed column names, at the very most pivoting by rownumber (which can also be fixed as you should have a maximum number of columns that you need)

Comment: dynamic column is something you shouldn't think in sql db rather have another table with oneToMany relationship

Comment: it is for the excel report so I need this form of representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Name1,Name2, Name3  from (
 SELECT     
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
      *
    FROM  
      Table1
       )  as t
PIVOT(
   max(  Id )
    FOR [Name] IN (
        [Name1], 
        [Name2], 
        [Name3]) 
        )AS pivot_table;
```

If you want it dynamic

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colnames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SET @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM  SHELL_CHEM_TEST.dbo.Table1
ORDER BY 1
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,1,'')


SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @colnames + ' from
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn, *
from  Table1
) x
pivot
(
max(Id)
for Name in (' + @colnames + ')
) p '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```